# Receive information through the socket does not work properly

Tags: android, sockets, multiplayer

I am developing a multiplayer android game, which is sending information through sockets. The game is working fine, but sometimes, it seems that the information that is being sent does not get received. Therefore, I would like a way to ensure that the information goes through. Is this possible?

Comment: "Sockets" = "Network Sockets"? What protocol? UDP? TCP?

Comment: I use TCP and send information over http

Comment: "ensure that the information goes through" - "Through" from the device to the server, or "through" from one device to another device via the server?

Comment: HTTP/TCP does not fail silently. Either the connection and data transfer went through, or you'll get an exception. So could you please provide more detail as to what you mean by "sometimes [...] information that is being sent does not get received"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure it yourself,(i'm assuming you are developping the server side as well.) For exemple you can create a server response for each message you send through the socket and try to resend this message as long as the server don't respond correctly.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate now that the poster has clarified they are using TCP - because of that, they *do not* have to ensure it themselves, as the protocol already does this.